# How to configure a Ninja install on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I created a CMake-supporting C++ project in *[Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio)* and everything works perfectly.

I saw that the native build system is *Ninja*, and I would like to get a standalone library folder like when you type:

```
make -j8 install.
```

which the equivalent could be:

```
ninja install.
```

My CMake scripts are supported to do this.
But when I build my project I see there is no Ninja install.

So I tried to configure in:
menu *File → *Settings* and *in the project → opening open-module-settings.*
But there is nothing to configure Ninja native build or NDK configuration.

Here the samples:

[image: Android studio configuration]

*Just to know where I can configure the Ninja options in the Android Studio or in Gradle files.*

My configuration:

- Android Studio 2.3.1
- build-tools: 25.0.2
- CMake 3.6.5
- Gradle 3.3

Answer (score 0):

By default, `ninja.build` files are generated in `</path/to/your/app>/Application/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/<build-type>/<arch-name>`.

There you can run `ninja`. If you have set up an `install` target, you can call it so. The default folders of the compiled libraries will be something like `</path/to/your/app>/Application/build/intermediates/cmake/<build-type>/obj/<arch-name>`.

Comment: Can you add an example of a path?

Comment: @PeterMortensen what do you mean? What is missing for the example paths I wrote? `build-type` is usually heavily dependent on the project itself, but it can be "Debug" for instance. `arch-name` can be, for instance "x86" or some of the arm variations, something like "arm" or "aarch64"